# TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchContact' of undefined

Tags: javascript, class

i can't find the problem, i can't see anything which i haven't defined nor misspelled please help, i know there are some irrelevant code here but if i leave it out you might not understand what im trying to do with my code, yes im a beginner so i don't know any high level methods so the code is so long

```
class AddressBook{
    constructor(){
        this.myContact=[];
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Homer", 98849959));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Marge", 84774744));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Lisa", 86994994));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Maggie", 94775883));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Bart", 88838848));
        var input = require("readline-sync");
        console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
        var choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
        while(choice != 3){
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    this.showAllContacts();
                    console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
                    choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    search();
                    console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
                    choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
                    choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
            }
        console.log("Good bye!");
    }
    searchContact(nameFind){
        var found = false;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.myContact.length ; i++){
            if(this.myContact[i].name == nameFind){
                found = true;
                return(this.myContact[i]);
            }
        }
        if(found == false){
            return("not found!");
        }
    }
}

function search(){
    var input = require("readline-sync");
    var nameSearch = input.question("Enter name of the contact: ");
    var b = myAddressBook.searchContact(nameSearch);
    if(b != "not found!"){
        console.log(b.name+"'s phone number is "+b.mobileNumber);
    }
    else{
        console.log(b);
    }
}
var myAddressBook = new AddressBook();
```

i should be getting back the name and phone number but im getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchContact' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `search` (the function that causes the error because of the `myAddressBook.searchContact(nameSearch)` call) before the `AddressBook` constructor returns which means that at that point `myAddressBook` is `undefined` because `new AddressBook()` hasn't returned yet.

To fix that, you can move the code that calls `search` outside the constructor, here is an example:

```
class AddressBook{
    constructor(){
        this.myContact=[];
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Homer", 98849959));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Marge", 84774744));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Lisa", 86994994));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Maggie", 94775883));
        this.myContact.push(new Contact("Bart", 88838848));
        var input = require("readline-sync");        
    }

    userInteraction () {
        console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
        var choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
        while(choice != 3){
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    this.showAllContacts();
                    console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
                    choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    search();
                    console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
                    choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Personal Addressbook\n----------------------\n(1) Show All Contacts\n(2) Search Contact\n(3) Exit\n");
                    choice = input.questionInt(">>> ");
            }
        console.log("Good bye!");
    }
    ....
}
....
var myAddressBook = new AddressBook();
myAddressBook.userInteraction();
```

Comment: well do you have any suggestions on how i could fix it? because i really have no idea

Comment: so to confirm, the reason it was showing up as undefined was because of my while loop not having been broken out of, so despite the new AddressBook, nothing was returned it was still undefined?

Comment: @EthanLow Yes, `myAddressBook` is set only after the `constructor` function returns, the loop in the constructor is preventing that and it contains a call to `search` which used this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, need to change this (unclosed while):

```
        }
    console.log("Good bye!");
}
searchContact(nameFind){
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.myContact.length ; i++){
```

For this (closing while bracket):

```
        }
    }
    console.log("Good bye!");
}
searchContact(nameFind){
    var found = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < this.myContact.length ; i++){
```